# Apply scripts and styles to iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, parent

I'm trying to create a small editor for a website. One of the features is a drag and drop interface. I'd like for the user to be able to drag elements to another position in the page. I was thinking of having an iFrame of the site, and applying JS and CSS to enable drag and drop ability.

Here's a screenshot of a CMS that does that:

[image: CMS]

The site is an iFrame. When I open the iFrame, you can't drag and drop elements. So, I'm assuming that they somehow apply changes in the parent page. Is there any way that I can basically add Javascript into the iFrame?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page. I also just found this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhODHoaats0&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As long as the page that the `iframe` references is on the same domain**, yes, you can. You can apply scripting and styling on elements within your `iframe` just like you'd do to any element in your main parent page. The main syntax is this:

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById("your_iframe_id");
/*ifrm.contentWindow.document is the document within the iframe
so let's try styling a div with an id 'mydiv' inside the iframe:*/
ifrm.contentWindow.document.getElementById("mydiv").style.color = "red";
```

Of course this is just a sample, you can use the same mechanism to do more complex stuff with elements within the `iframe` (including drag and drop!)

You could, as well, execute functions that are defined within the `iframe` from the parent page. The syntax is similar and intuitive:

```
ifrm.contentWindow.yourFunction();
```

I hope that helped you in any manner!

Comment: It's not working for me.  I have the ids and iframes correct, but it won't work.  The iframe IS in the same folder.

Comment: @Caleb Check your browser's error log. A demo would be great.

Comment: The code [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument) worked

Comment: I think IE uses `contentDocument` rather than `contentWindow`. What a pain.